# Finding Aggregate Root for Entity

Tags: domain-driven-design

I need to design a system where set of *tasks* can be defined then *template*/*workflow* would be defined by choosing some the tasks. If I make *template* as the aggregate root, then I wont be able to define the task using this root. If I make both task and template as Aggregate roots, then I would be missing to define the fact that template contains tasks. Can you please suggest whats the right approach over here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that template contains tasks is somewhat irrelevant to what the aggregate root is.

Remember that an aggregate is really only a consistency (in the distributed sense) or isolation (in the database sense) boundary: everything within the aggregate appears to change as a unit.  So the question is then if it should be acceptable to operate on multiple tasks in a template simultaneously and independently.

Consider a template *A* with tasks *X* and *Y*.  We have two independent (e.g. different HTTP requests, or messages from a bus, etc.) operations *I* (changing *X* in some way) and *J* (changing *Y* in some way).  Could whether *I* is a valid operation depend on the result of *J*?  Could whether *J*  is a valid operation depend on the result of *I*?

If the answer to at least one of those questions is "yes", then that points to template being the aggregate root and tasks being sub-entities in that aggregate.  If the answers for all pairs of operations on *X* and *Y* is "no", then you can have task be an aggregate root (you don't have to, though there are generally advantages to having aggregates be as small as possible).

Note that even if tasks is a separate aggregate from template, a template can still refer to a task, but only by ID.  For instance, rather than having a field of type `Task`, it could have a field of type `String`: an operation on a template could be "get task id" and based on the resulting ID, you perform some other operation on the task with that ID (but performing this operation is a separate transaction from the "get task id" operation's transaction).  Similarly, the task aggregate can refer to its containing template by ID, though note that this is somewhat weaker than foreign keys in a relational schema (note that such keys effectively fuse the aggregates and obscure the aggregate root...).

Comment: Task creation happens before to Template creation. If Template is made as the aggregate root and Tasks as an entities inside , then how can client access the entities (As template doesn’t yet exist) ?

Comment: If task creation has to precede template creation, then tasks can't be entities in the template aggregate (and tasks also would have to be allowed to be part of no template).